# multiple workers looking on the same port: nginx mess!

Tags: networking, server, 22.04, nginx

I have exactly one test machine running different applications: a client and a server.

The client responds to the port `3000`, while the server responds to the port `3001`.

I setup nginx as a reverse proxy, and allows the user to connect to my domain:

The client should respond to the following names: `domain.net`, `www.domain.net` and `idsm.comain.net`

while the server should respond to `server.domain.net`.

My nginx default file is the following

```
server {

    server_name domain.net www.domain.net idsm.domain.net;
    
    location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {

    server_name server.domain.net;
    
    location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = idsm.domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.net www.domain.net idsm.domain.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = server.domain.net) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name server.domain.net;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I added the certiticates using certbot as always: For me everything looks correct.

Then `nginx -t` returned no error.

Then I launched `systemctl start nginx` which returned no error.

The `system status nginx` returned the following:

```
root@neo4j:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-11-19 19:03:53 CET; 2s ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 36872 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 36873 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 36874 (nginx)
      Tasks: 9 (limit: 76087)
     Memory: 9.9M
        CPU: 58ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─36874 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             ├─36875 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─36876 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─36877 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─36878 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─36879 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─36880 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─36881 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             └─36882 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

nov 19 19:03:53 neo4j systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
nov 19 19:03:53 neo4j systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Everything looks nice and seems correct.

But nothing run, and if I launch `nginx` the result is as follow:

```
root@neo4j:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
root@neo4j:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled#
```

the config file is the only one in sites-enabled.

Apache2 has been uninstalled from the server.

There are exactly 8 processes listening to the port 80 and they are those of the nginx workers (from 36875 to 36882).

1. I don't understand why there are so many (8) worker processes (could be because I have 8 cores?).
2. I cannot understand why the nginx doesn't start and is unable to bind.

==============================================================

After the Thomas Ward comment, I run `sudo ss -tulpn | grep 443` and this is the result:

```
sudo ss -tulpn | grep 443
[sudo] password di neo4j: 
tcp   LISTEN 0      511            0.0.0.0:443        0.0.0.0:*    users:(("nginx",pid=43361,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43360,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43359,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43358,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43357,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43356,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43355,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43354,fd=7),("nginx",pid=43353,fd=7))
tcp   LISTEN 0      511               [::]:443           [::]:*    users:(("nginx",pid=43361,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43360,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43359,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43358,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43357,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43356,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43355,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43354,fd=6),("nginx",pid=43353,fd=6))
```

But why all those `nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)` with should mean that a port is already used?

Then I try to restate the question:

I have a react application running on port= 3000

If I run `http://idsm.domain.net` in the browser, it returns `502: bad gateway`.

Why?

Comment: what do you mean "nothing is run"?  SystemD shows you that NGINX is in fact running.  What does `sudo ss -tulpn | grep 443` show?  What makes you think nginx is not running?

Comment: Those "unknown error" notices are because you're already running NGINX and it's already *bound* to those ports - I chose 443 as an example.  502 Bad Gateway means that your `proxy_pass` to backend systems are failing and those backend ports (port 3000, 3001, etc.) are not reachable when NGINX hands off to the backend.  Meaning it's not an nginx issue, it's your backend applications that're broke